# how we can create subcategories of a category using script in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

As i tried with this code , this seems fine but only few subcategory are created and few not. I am not getting the problem.Please tell me if there's something missing.

```
$catIdOfTransport='112';
wp_create_category('car',$catIdOfTransport) ;
$arr=array('maruti','nano','bmw');
$val=count($arr);
for($j=0;$j<$val;$j++){ wp_create_category( $arr[$j], 'car'); }
```

Comment: This should be posted on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp_create_category($values, $parent);

```
    $valow=strtolower($values);
    $slugcre=str_replace(" ","-",$valow);
    $slugname=$slugcre."-transpost";
    $idObj = get_category_by_slug($slugname); 

    $id = $idObj->term_id;
    $parent1=$id;
    $val=count($arr[$i]);

    for($j=0;$j<$val;$j++)
             {
                wp_create_category( $arr[$i][$j], $parent1);
             }
```

i think this code can help you .

Thanks